HttpClients & Certificate
Нашел код в котором в HttpClients подгружают сертификат. Зачем это делать на стороне клиента? Разве при рукопожатии сервер не отсылает тот же сертификат клиенту, который уже с помощью корневого сертификата его верифицирует?

https://ya.ru/search/?text=клиентский+сертификат
